# Law of total expectation and how prove that two variables are independent

Tags: conditional-expectation

I am confused in understanding the formal definition for independence and how does this differ from the law of total expectations.

I thought that $E[u|x]=E[u]$ formally means independence of $u$ and $x$.

However, when I have $E[u|x]=a$ (const) and use the law of total expectations,

$E[u]=E[E[u|x]]=a$

I obtain $E[u]=a$

Don't I have then $a=E[u|x]$ and $a=E[u] \implies a=E[u|x]=E[u] \implies \text{independence between x and u}$?

Something does not add up, as this would mean that we can always establish independence between two variables. Where is my error in thinking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's impossible to read minds, so to locate any error in thinking let's help you work through as simple an example as possible using the most basic possible definitions and axioms of probability.

Consider a sample space $\Omega = \{au, bu, cu, av, bv, cv\}$ ("$au$" etc. are just names of six abstract things) where all subsets are considered measurable.  Define a probability $\mathbb{P}$ on $\Omega$ in terms of its values on the atoms via

$$\mathbb{P}(au) = \mathbb{P}(cu) = p,\ \mathbb{P}(bu) = r-2p;\quad \mathbb{P}(av) = \mathbb{P}(cv) = q,\ \mathbb{P}(bv) = 1-r-2q$$

where $p,q,r$ are any numbers for which all six probabilities are positive.  For instance, we may take $p=1/6$, $q=1/8$, and $r=1/2$.  Because the sum of the six given probabilities is unity, this defines a valid probability measure.

Define the random variables $U$ and $X$ as

$$U(\omega)=-1, 0, 1$$

depending on whether the initial letter in the name of $\omega$ is $a$, $b$, or $c$ respectively; and

$$X(\omega) = 0,1$$

depending on whether the final letter in the name of $\omega$ is $u$ or $v$ respectively.

This can be neatly summarized in a $3$ by $2$ table of probabilities, headed by values of $U$ and $X$, whose interpretation I trust is evident:

$$\begin{array}{r|cc}
  & \text{X=0} & \text{X=1} \\
\hline
 \text{U=-1} & p & q \\
 \text{U=0} & r-2 p & 1-r-2 q \\
 \text{U=1} & p & q
\end{array}$$

It is then easy to compute the following:

1. $\mathbb{P}(X=0) = \mathbb{P}(\{au,bu,cu\}) = p + r-2p + p = r$ (sum the left column in the table).
2. $\mathbb{P}(U=-1) = \mathbb{P}(\{au,av\}) = p+q$ (sum the top row in the table).

***Independence*** means nothing other than probabilities multiply.  This would imply, among other things, that

$$p = \mathbb{P}(au) = \mathbb{P}(X=0, U=-1) = \mathbb{P}(X=0)\mathbb{P}(U=-1) = r(p+q)$$

(investigate the top left entry in the table).  But this is rarely the case; for instance, $1/6 \ne (1/2)(1/6 + 1/8)$.  Therefore **$X$ and $U$ are not independent** (except for some special possible combinations of $p$, $q$, and $r$). However,

$$\mathbb{E}(U) = \mathbb{P}(U=-1)(-1) +  \mathbb{P}(U=0)(0) + \mathbb{P}(U=1)(1) = 0$$

That is, the expectation of $U$ is zero. (This should be obvious from the symmetry: the chance that $U=1$ balances the chance that $U=-1$ regardless of the value of $X$.)  However,

$$\mathbb{E}(U|X=0) = \mathbb{P}(U=-1, X=0)(-1) + \cdots + \mathbb{P}(U=1, X=0)(1) = 0,$$

and similarly $$\mathbb{E}(U|X=1) = 0.$$  That is, the conditional expectation of $U$--which is a *function*--has the constant value zero.  In symbols, we have found that

$$\mathbb{E}(U|X) = 0 = \mathbb{E}(U)$$

and we have a simple, explicit example showing why **constant conditional expectation does not imply independence.**

Comment: (+1) Nice answer. A minor typo: in the computation of $\mathbb{E}(U\mid  X=0)$, it should be $P(U=-1\mid X = 0)$, etc (the conditional, not the joint). Doesn't change the result, of course.

Comment: oh wow, great answer! So independence stems from independence in probability... Can I ask why classical regression models claim u and x are independent? Is this because when they assume u and x being jointly normal distributed and we have  strict exogenity, this would imply their independence in probability?

Comment: Thanks @Zen: you are correct that the conditional notation should be used at first and then that should be equated with the joint probabilities.

Comment: Majte In most regression models $x$ is not a random variable. It is a value set by the experimenter who observes a response; *for simplicity,* variations in the response are assumed not to depend on $x$, *until proven otherwise*: there's no "claim" made. In so-called "mixed" models $x$ is random. If the errors are thought to depend on $x$, that has to be included in the model in a *quantitative* way. Many such models exist; for instance, heteroscedastic responses are modeled in this way, as well as correlations induced by grouping, repeated measures, etc.

Comment: Fine, @whuber. Sorry for nitpicking. It is cool to think how many times this answer will be hit by people googling **constant conditional expectation does not imply independence**. Probably, forever.

Comment: To follow up on my original question and associated confusion, so when we have $E[u_i|x_i]=E[u_i]=0$ it does NOT imply (assuming conditional homoskedasticity) that $V[u_i|x_i]=V[u_i]=σ^2$. But if $u_i$ and $x_i$ were truly independent as within the probability space or as in their joint density being equal to the product of their marginal densities, we could assert this claim of $V[u_i|x_i]=V[u_i]$? In other words, independence implies $E[u_i|x_i]=E[u_i]$ and $V[u_i|x_i]=V[u_i]$ but usually never the other way around?

Comment: I don't understand the first part of that comment, Majte (because I'm missing some of the context), but the statement following "in other words" is correct.

Comment: What I meant is, once we established independence, it ought to work for all moments, e.g. $E[u_i^d|x_i]=E[u_i^d]$. However, if we have just the constant conditional expectation, we cannot assert such claim? (Perhaps read my previous duplicate post, which should now make more sense)

Comment: (+1, awhile ago) My favorite example of this is $(X,Y)$ distributed uniform on $\{(1,0), (0,1), (-1,0), (0,-1)\}$. In that case you get $\mathbb E(X \mid Y) = \mathbb E(Y \mid X) = 0 = \mathbb E X = \mathbb E Y$ but $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

Comment: @Cardinal I began with that one but somehow--through some error--felt early on that I could not make a counterexample of it. What you see here was the result of the next step.  Sorry about the extra complexity...

Comment: Quick note: after just a few hours, Google already ranks it first when I search for **constant conditional expectation does not imply independence**.

Comment: Does this mean I am getting famous for my stupidity and I don't have to even undress for that? :-)

Comment: @whuber: I like the example, in particular, because a simple rigid transformation (45 degree rotation) preserves all four of the expected values but results in two independent random variables. Most people respond with disbelief initially; those that think about it further tend to come away with a better understanding of these matters.

Comment: ...also, no need to apologize for the "extra complexity". I'm glad it's there because it shows that simple one-off examples like the one I mentioned aren't just parlor tricks.